# Missing required whitespace on connection string

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I downloaded an MVC asp.net project from GitHub, it came with his SQL database but I've encountered several issues relating to the visual studio project connected to the database, a friend told me that should change the connection strings to make them my own so they can work with my SQL server.

so this is the original connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TrabajoFinalWeb-20180619072956.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TrabajoFinalWeb-20180619072956;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="RestauranteEntitiesContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Restaurante.csdl|res://*/Models.Restaurante.ssdl|res://*/Models.Restaurante.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PERU\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Restaurante;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and this is the one I made:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name = "DefaultConnection" connectionString=" Data Source=Desktop-PGPVKTQ\MSSQLSERVER;Database="Restaurante;Application" Name="TrabajoFinalWeb;Integrated Security= True"/>
<add name="RestauranteEntitiesContext" connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Desktop-PGPVKTQ\MSSQLSERVER;initial catalog=Restaurante;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any input is appreciated I really need the help.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you format your connection string: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You really have butchered those connection strings. The first one:

> Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TrabajoFinalWeb-20180619072956.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TrabajoFinalWeb-20180619072956;Integrated Security=True

You need to change the `Data Source` value, you need to remove the `AttachDbFilename` attribute and you need to change `Initial Catalog` value.

There is no SQL Server instance named 'MSSQLSERVER'. That's the default instance, so you don't use an instance name at all. Apparently your database is named 'Restaurante':

> Data Source=Desktop-PGPVKTQ;Initial Catalog=Restaurante;Integrated Security=True

Done!

You made an even greater meal of the second one because you've removed all the EF stuff. All you need to do is change the data source:

> metadata=res://*/Models.Restaurante.csdl|res://*/Models.Restaurante.ssdl|res://*/Models.Restaurante.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Desktop-PGPVKTQ;initial catalog=Restaurante;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;